# r split on delimiter not in parentheses

Tags: regex, r

I am currently trying to split a string on the pipe delimiter:

```
999|150|222|(123|145)|456|12,260|(10|10000)
```

The catch is I don't want to split on `|` inside of parentheses, I only want to split on this character outside of parentheses.

This is just splitting on every `|` character, yielding the results I don't want:

```
x <- '999|150|222|(123|145)|456|12,260|(10|10000)'
m <- strsplit(x, '\\|')

[[1]]
[1] "999"    "150"    "222"    "(123"   "145)"   "456"    "12,260" "(10"   
[9] "10000)"
```

I am looking to get the following results keeping everything inside of parentheses:

```
[[1]]
[1] "999"        "150"        "222"        "(123|145)"  "456"       
[6] "12,260"     "(10|10000)"
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can switch on [`PCRE`](http://www.pcre.org/) by using `perl=T` and some dark magic:

```
x <- '999|150|222|(123|145)|456|12,260|(10|10000)'
strsplit(x, '\\([^)]*\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\\|', perl=T)

# [[1]]
# [1] "999"        "150"        "222"        "(123|145)"  "456"       
# [6] "12,260"     "(10|10000)"
```

The idea is to **skip** content in parentheses. [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bO1cF2/4)

On the left side of the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) we match anything in parentheses *making the subpattern **fail** and force the regular expression engine to not retry the substring using backtracking control*. The right side of the alternation operator matches `|` (*outside of parentheses, **what we want...***)

Answer (score 6):

One option:

```
scan(text=gsub("\\(|\\)", "'", x), what='', sep="|")
#[1] "999"      "150"      "222"      "123|145"  "456"      "12,260"   "10|10000"
```

Here's another way using `strsplit`. There are other answers here using `strsplit`, but this seems to be the simplest pattern that works:

```
strsplit(x, "\\|(?!\\d+\\))", perl=TRUE)
# [1] "999"        "150"        "222"        "(123|145)"  "456"        "12,260"     "(10|10000)"
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work

```
x <- '999|150|222|(123|145)|456|12,260|(10|10000)'
m <- strsplit(x, '\\|(?=[^)]+(\\||$))', perl=T)

# [[1]]
# [1] "999"        "150"        "222"        "(123|145)"  "456"        "12,260"    
# [7] "(10|10000)"
```

Here we not just split on the `|` but we also use a look ahead to make sure that there are no ")" marks before the next `|` or the end of the string. Note that this method doesn't require or ensure the parenthesis are balanced and closed. We assume your input is well formatted.