# RegEx for matching all commas unless they are enclosed between parentheses or brackets

Tags: r, string, strsplit

Consider the following code in R:

```
x <- "A, B (C, D, E), F, G [H, I, J], K (L (M, N), O), P (Q (R, S (T, U)))"
strsplit(x, split = "some regex here")
```

I would like this to return something resembling a list containing the character vector

```
"A"
"B (C, D, E)"
"F"
"G [H, I, J]"
"K (L (M, N), O)"
"P (Q (R, S (T, U)))"
```

EDIT: The proposed alternative questions do not answer my question, since nested parentheses and brackets are allowed, and it is possible for *n*-level nesting to occur (beyond 2).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940561/r-split-on-delimiter-not-in-parentheses.

Comment: You say something did not work, but what did you try that did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a job for a custom parser than a single regex. I would love to be proved wrong, but while we're waiting, here's a very pedestrian parsing function that gets the job done.

```r
parse_nested <- function(string) {
  
  chars <- strsplit(string, "")[[1]]
  
  parentheses <- numeric(length(chars))
  parentheses[chars == "("] <- 1
  parentheses[chars == ")"] <- -1
  parentheses <- cumsum(parentheses)

  brackets <- numeric(length(chars))
  brackets[chars == "["] <- 1
  brackets[chars == "]"] <- -1
  brackets <- cumsum(brackets)
  
  split_on <- which(brackets == 0 & parentheses == 0 & chars == ",")
  split_on <- c(0, split_on, length(chars) + 1)
  
  result <- character()
  
  for(i in seq_along(head(split_on, -1))) {
    x <- paste0(chars[(split_on[i] + 1):(split_on[i + 1] - 1)], collapse = "")
    result <- c(result, x)
  }
  
  trimws(result)
}
```

Which produces:

```r
parse_nested(x)
#> [1] "A"                   "B (C, D, E)"         "F"                  
#> [4] "G [H, I, J]"         "K (L (M, N), O)"     "P (Q (R, S (T, U)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex` only. Since `stringr` does not allow for recursion, we need to use base R.

```r
x <- "A, B (C, D, E), F, G [H, I, J], K (L (M, N), O), P (Q (R, S (T, U)))"

regmatches(x, 
  gregexpr("([A-Z] )*([\\(\\[](?>[^()\\[\\]]|(?R))*[\\)\\]])|[A-Z]", 
            x, perl = TRUE))

#> [[1]]
#> [1] "A"                   "B (C, D, E)"         "F"                  
#> [4] "G [H, I, J]"         "K (L (M, N), O)"     "P (Q (R, S (T, U)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses `getTerms` from [Terms of a sum in a R expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300717/terms-of-a-sum-in-a-r-expression/53300817#53300817) rather than regexes.  This function is quite short with a 3 line body.

Assuming that there are no plus signs convert each comma to plus, convert to a language object and then use `getTerms` to explode that into individual terms. At the end deparse each term to a string and convert the plus signs back to commas.

```
x |>
  chartr(",", "+", x = _) |>
  str2lang() |>
  getTerms() |>
  sapply(\(x) chartr("+", ",", deparse1(x)))
```

giving

```
[1] "A"                  "B(C , D , E)"       "F"                 
[4] "G[H , I , J]"       "K(L(M , N) , O)"    "P(Q(R , S(T , U)))"
```

If spacing matters use this slightly longer code

```
x |>
  chartr(",", "+", x = _) |>
  str2lang() |>
  getTerms() |>
  sapply(\(x) x |> 
    deparse1() |>
    gsub(" +", ",", x = _, fixed = TRUE) |>
    gsub("(", " (", x = _, fixed = TRUE) |>        
    gsub("[", " [", x = _, fixed = TRUE)
  )
```

giving

```
[1] "A"                   "B (C, D, E)"         "F"                  
[4] "G [H, I, J]"         "K (L (M, N), O)"     "P (Q (R, S (T, U)))"
```

### Note

The input `x` in the question is this string

```
x <- "A, B (C, D, E), F, G [H, I, J], K (L (M, N), O), P (Q (R, S (T, U)))"
```